# how to override GET method in django to make a seen status

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I wanna make this thing on the model as I'm using REST API too.

I have a model named as `Seen`

```
class Seen(models.Model):
    seen = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name=_("Is active"), default=True,
        help_text=_("Inactive devices will not be sent notifications")
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        SETTINGS["USER_MODEL"], blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    post = models.ForeignKey(Posts)
```

and I wanna to override my custom class-based view, so that everytime an authenticated user visits a `DetailView` I create an instance of the `Seen`.

Comment: please show what you have tried yet.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet except for making the seen modelPost

Answer (score 0):

In your class-based view you can override method `get`:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # fetch your values from request.GET.get('key')
    # and play around with it
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Or since you're using `DetailView`:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    # key for Post's id (consider it as 'id'),  you maybe named it differently
    post_id = self.kwargs.get('id') 
    if post_id is None:
        raise Http404
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id) # fetch your post
        user = self.request.user # considering your user is authenticated
        # Create Seen object and save it with params,
        # seen field is optional, since you set defaul value
        seen_object = Seen.objects.create(post=post, user=user, seen=True)
    except Post.DoesNotExist: # if wrong id was passed
        raise Http404
    return post # return an object for your DetailView
```

P.S.: To make sure that your user is authenticated add `LoginRequiredMixin` to your view, like: `PostDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView)` and set `login_url='login'`